# Creating JPEG images of geoprocessing output using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm running batch processing on several datasets using a standalone EXE written in .NET. There are many output files for each dataset (>25 featureclasses/rasters). For every dataset I would like to grab a few specific outputs and create JPEG images of them for simple quality control. Ideally I would combine a few of the featureclasses together and create an image of the combination as if I were exporting an image of several layers as you can do using the Arc UI. I imagine that there will be a few steps involved in accomplishing this - can someone point me in the right direction?

For the sake of simplicity, you can assume that I have the full path to the files I want, which are stored in a FGDB on a drive. I can also derive the approximate extent of these featureclasses from the largest of them, so I can set a view extent.

**For example:**

I have just run the extension and created a series of output files which are stored in a FGDB. These featureclasses/rasters all cover the same discrete area and are projected.

Outputs (making these up for simplicity):

1) DEM of the area (represents the full extent).

2) Polyline road network.

3) Polygon building footprints.

4) Point featureclass representing manhole covers.

What to accomplish:

Combine all of the files in the correct order (featureclasses overtop of the DEM) and save a JPEG file.

**EDIT:**

My extension runs as an EXE (not a toolbar) and doesn't actually open the Arc UI - it merely consumes the licenses and does the processing in the background. So, do I have access to ActiveView if I haven't "launched" the UI? Essentially, I don't have a TOC to populate with layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ArcObjects to add and arrange the order of layers in the ArcMap TOC, I would first search for the specific names that you want to export out as a group.  Then turn off all the layers except for those that you want to export out e.g.

```
'Search for MyLayer1 and MyLayer2 in the ArcMap TOC
 Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer = Nothing
        Dim pLayer As ILayer
        Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer

        m_pMap2 = m_pMxDoc2.ActiveView.FocusMap
        pEnumLayer = m_pMap2.Layers

        pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
        Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
                    If pLayer.Name = "MyLayer1" AND pLayer.Name = "MyLayer2" Then
               TurnOffLayers()         
ExportActiveView()
    Else
    Exit Sub
                End If
                pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
            Loop
End Sub
```

If those layers are present then you can use the ExportActiveView code to export out the jpg images.  Here is the link for the [ExportActiveView Code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000026000000).

**Edit**

You could add those layers into an ArcMap project, save the mxd, and export out the map using python/arcpy script.

[Add Layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/AddLayer/00s300000025000000/)

[Export Map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ExportToJPEG/00s300000038000000/)

OR

if you have access to the extension code you could use 'Call Shell' code to open up ArcMap, and add your layers in the TOC using ArcObjects.

A python script might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will this method work if I don't have the Arc UI open? I'll edit my question to elaborate, but my extension runs as an EXE and doesn't actually open the Arc UI - it merely consumes the licenses and does the processing in the background. So, do I have access to ActiveView if I haven't "launched" the UI? Essentially, I don't have a TOC to populate with layers.

Comment: @Radar, See my Edit.

Comment: @radar Usually "extension" means something that is running in same process as the arcmap.exe (or arccatalog.exe).  If this is not the case you probably should re-phrase you question, changing "extension" to "standalone exe".

Comment: artwork21 - thanks for updating and addressing my comment. Your answer got me to where I need to be - I'll with my resulting methods once I get the finer details sorted out. @Kirk - I suppose the semantics are a little odd given how I've implemented this EXE. I'll update based on your suggestions.