# ArcObjects - Create a map in the background from layers and save as JPG

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

Given a series of map layers is it possible to arrange them in some order, add basic map features (north arrow, scale bar) and then save the result as a JPG. I'd like to accomplish this in the background as a button-triggered event in an ArcMap Add-On.

I've seen [ExportActiveView](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000026000000), but I think this will only work if I have the map layers already loaded into the ActiveView and on the users' screen.

Is it possible to create this map behind the scenes?

Comment: I'm guessing your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15987/creating-jpeg-images-of-geoprocessing-output-using-arcobjects provides a little more background in a different context (for instance that your data lives in a File GeoDatabase, etc)? It doesn't bother me, I am just curious if this is correct.

Comment: @Radar, FYI this all may be done using python/arcpy too.  Adding layers and exporting map.  It will take more less code to develop.  You could just reference a template mxd that has your layout controls already positioned and created.

Comment: @elrobis You can consider that question irrelevant for the purpose of this one - I just have map layers coming in and I need a JPG out, all done in the background (e.g. not on screen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something similar I have done in the past is use IMapDocument.  It does require a hard file, so I just create a temp file for the process, and delete after the export.  In the code snippet below, the MapExportFormat is a little enumerator I created representing different output formats (pdf,gif,png).

```
private static void ExportMap(IMapDocument map,MapExportFormat exportFormat, string outputFile)
        {
            int OUTPUT_RES = 600;
            IExport export = null;

            switch (exportFormat)
            {
                case MapExportFormat.PDF:
                    IExportPDF pdfExport = new ExportPDFClass();
                    pdfExport.ImageCompression = esriExportImageCompression.esriExportImageCompressionDeflate;
                    pdfExport.EmbedFonts = true;
                    pdfExport.Compressed = true;
                    //IExportPDF2 pdfExport2 = (IExportPDF2)pdfExport;
                    //pdfExport2.ExportPDFLayersAndFeatureAttributes = esriExportPDFLayerOptions.esriExportPDFLayerOptionsLayersOnly;
                    export = (IExport)pdfExport;
                    break;
                case MapExportFormat.GIF:
                    IExportGIF gifExport = new ExportGIFClass();
                    export = (IExport)gifExport;
                    break;
                case MapExportFormat.JPG:
                    IExportJPEG jpgExport = new ExportJPEGClass();
                    export = (IExport)jpgExport;
                    break;
                case MapExportFormat.PNG:
                    IExportPNG pngExport = new ExportPNGClass();
                    export = (IExport)pngExport;
                    break;

            }

            export.Resolution = OUTPUT_RES;
            export.ExportFileName = outputFile;

            tagRECT exportFrame = map.ActiveView.ExportFrame;
            IEnvelope exportEnvelope = new EnvelopeClass();
            exportEnvelope.PutCoords(exportFrame.left, exportFrame.top, exportFrame.right, exportFrame.bottom);
            export.PixelBounds = exportEnvelope;

            int hdc = export.StartExporting();
            map.ActiveView.Output(hdc, OUTPUT_RES,exportFrame,null,null);
            export.FinishExporting();
            export.Cleanup();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and code snippet. In your example does all of the work happen off-screen? Can ActiveView be used without actually showing it to the user in ArcMap?

Comment: Sure does.  I did everything from a button click in a form totally outside of ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. One additional point. When working from within an ESRI Add-On and exporting a map document that is not currently on screen, it's best to set the activeView to mapdoc.PageLayout - if you don't set it to the layout view the map unit-to-pixel conversion gets mangled and you end up with image dimensions that are very large and can't be handled by the export.FinishExporting method - it error checks this.

Comment: How do you create the IMapDocument? In my example i had to create a dummy mxd. Like: IMapDocument ipMapDoc; ipMapDoc = new MapDocumentClass(); ipMapDoc.Open(@"D:\Data\Spatial\Untitled.mxd"); Is there any way to get around this?