# ExportToPDF creates blank PDF

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, export, pdf

I have a MapDocument that I am trying to export to PDF. I am using [this example.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000026000000) However, it always says it is finished but when I open the pdf file there is nothing in it. I have tried exporting to a TIFF but with the same results. Is there a known reason why this might be happening?

When it brings up the ArcMap program, it displays everything properly and I can manually export to PDF from the program just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended with the same result months before and I could not found a solution using `IPrintAndExport`. I would recommend to use the`IExport`directly. Please have a look at the following [ExportActiveView function in this example in VBA](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Cartography/Printing_and_Exporting/ExportActiveView.htm) or this post to a different topic with an [example in C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24722/arcobjects-create-a-map-in-the-background-from-layers-and-save-as-jpg). This works without problems in my case. You can simply exchange the ExportJPEG instance by the format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same blank PDF issue when creating a winforms program to ArcMap to do automation tasks.
Reading the [official documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#AppAutomation.htm) and specifically [this discussion](https://community.esri.com/thread/20407), I realize it is due to the processing space issue.
I resolve the issue by create the ExportPDF and PrintAndExport instance via IObjectFactory.

```cs
IObjectFactory oj = _app as IObjectFactory; //_app is the IApplication obtained via ((new MxDocument() as IDocument).Parent) as IApplication
IExport docExport = (IExport) oj.Create("esriOutput.ExportPDF");;
IPrintAndExport docPrintExport = (IPrintAndExport)oj.Create("esriCarto.PrintAndExport");
```